# Insert number as folderID

Tags: python, django, rest

I'm getting a new little problem with API Rest Python between Django and LogicalDOC.
I'm creating a folder inside LogicalDOC, then I would like to save my pdf file inside this new folder taking the `folderId`.

But, when it seems work because the syntax is good from my point of view : none pdf file appears.

I create a folder, I pick up his ID number : 348930 for example with the command `data["id"]` and I insert `str(data["id"])` in `FolderId` when I want to save my pdf file in the new folder.

The new folder is created and worked well, but the pdf file is not save inside. Something wrong ?

This is my script :

```
@login_required
def BirthCertificate_PDF(request, id) :

    birthcertificate = get_object_or_404(BirthCertificate, pk=id)

    data = {"birthcertificate" : birthcertificate}

    template = get_template('BC_raw.html')
    html  = template.render(Context(data))


    filename_directory = str(BirthCertificate.objects.get(pk=id).lastname.encode('utf-8')) + "_" + str(BirthCertificate.objects.get(pk=id).firstname.encode('utf-8')) + "_" + str(BirthCertificate.objects.get(pk=id).birthday)
    filename = 'Acte_Naissance_' + filename_directory + '.pdf'
    path = '/Users/valentinjungbluth/Desktop/Django/Individus/' + filename

    file = open(path, "w+b")
    pisaStatus = pisa.CreatePDF(html.encode('utf-8'), dest=file, encoding='utf-8')

    file.seek(0)
    pdf = file.read()
    if pdf :

        payload = '{{ "name":"{0}", "parentId":3309569 }}'.format(filename_directory) #Fix parent folder

        url = 'http://localhost:8080/services/rest/folder/create'
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'}
        resp = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers, auth=('admin', 'admin'))
        rbody = resp.content
        data = json.loads(rbody)

        print data["id"] #Get ID from the new folder

        payload = '{{ "language":"fr","fileName":"{0}","FolderId":'+str(data["id"]) +'}}'.format(filename)  #save pdf file inside the new folder thanks to his ID
        upfile = path
        files = { 
        'document': (None, payload, 'application/json'),
        'content': (os.path.basename(upfile), open(upfile, 'rb'), 'application/octet-stream')
        } 
        url = 'http://localhost:8080/services/rest/document/create'
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
        r = requests.post(url, files=files, headers=headers, auth=('admin', 'admin'))

        context = {"birthcertificate":birthcertificate,
                   "path":path}

        return render(request, 'BC_PDF.html', context)
    file.close()

    return HttpResponse(pdf, 'application/pdf')
```

This is a screen capture which shows that folderID should be : 3538970
This number is also given by : `data["id"]`

[image]

Comment: Try to specify folderid as second argument of format, like this: `payload = '{{ "language":"fr","fileName":"{0}","FolderId":"{1}"}}'.format(filename, str(data["id"]))`

Comment: @neverwalkaloner Still the same error, my pdf file is not saved in my new folder which was just created. I'm looking on format documentation. I've took account your edit before you wrote it ;)

Comment: Ok it was a syntax error : it's `folderId` and not `FolderId` ... Your answer works well ! As previously : make an answer and I will validate it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment you don't need to use string concatenation to pass FolderId as payload, just use second argument of [format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples) method:

```
d = '{{ "language":"fr","fileName":"{0}","FolderId":"{1}"}}'.format(‌​filename, str(data["id"]))
```

Comment: I didn't really know How format method worked. So thank you to your help.